# Can anyone tell me what SoapDocumentMethodAttribute does?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody explain to me what the following code does?  Specifically, the attribute on the GetStatus method.  I know it has something to do with SOAP requests, but I tried googling "SoapDocumentMethodAttribute" and didn't find much that explains things.  Can anybody dumb it down for me please?

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://dummyurl.com/", RequestNamespace = "http://dummyurl.com/", ResponseNamespace = "http://dummyurl.com/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public string GetStatus(string Username, string Password, string EndSystemUser) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("GetStatus", new object[] {
                    Username,
                    Password,
                    EndSystemUser});
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soap services expose WSDL to the consumers which contain information about how SOAP messages would be written.

This WSDL can be written either in **RPC** style or in **Document** Style.

Document style is perfered over RPC style as it means less coupling and provides better way to validate the message.

This attribute instructs WSDL generator **to use Document Style**.

From the [MSDN Documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Web Services Description Language (WSDL) defines two styles for how an
>   XML Web service method, which it calls an operation, can be formatted
>   in a SOAP message: RPC and Document. Document refers to formatting the
>   XML Web service method according to an XSD schema. The Document style
>   refers to formatting the Body element as a series of one or more
>   message parts following the Body element.

Refer [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27H_6.2.0/fa2ws_ovw_soap_syntax_lit.html) for examples of RPC / Document style.

Comment: In my example, what are the first 3 parameters specifying?

Comment: First parameter is to set the Action header in soap message.  This is generally used to identify the method which should be invoked after receiving soap message.

Comment: Second and Third parameter specify the xml namespaces for request soap message and response soap message.